# Change Eclipse Tab Icons

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm using Eclipse PDT Neon on Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to change Tab Icons. How can I do that?

I mean these Icons:

[image]

Comment: These icons are included in the plugins. I try will be quite difficult to change. Need to change the icon and rebuild the plugin

Comment: @Sravan Which plugin shows that? It seems to be embedded image file.

Comment: If you really want to see where the images, you may use plug-in image browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons are in the various plugin jars which provide the view, editor, menu, ....

Eclipse plugins are signed jars so you cannot just replace their contents as that will cause the signing to fail.